# How do I sell an expensive item online without offering a warranty?

Tags: selling, extended-warranty

We develop software for some international hardware firm. Recently, and given our good work, we were granted with some free hardware, which is kind of expensive (special computer processors). I thought about selling this on ebay. Firstly, I checked whether other users were selling the same item and at what price, and found some examples. So I placed my advertisement on eBay and was later contacted by a potential buyer. They asked me about the warranty on the item, of which there is none I can offer. What can I do now? Since it costs about 2000€ I do not know what my best options for listing and selling the item are.

Comment: Best option out of what? What are the options?

Comment: **which is kind of expensive**. That is the point. When somebody wants to spend so much money, he(she) would want to have some protection against the stuff going bad and he(she) losing his(her) investment. People would be wary of buying expensive stuff without warranty. Or else you will have to sell cheap. You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Paypal provides buyer protection for ebay so if you were to scam them with a DOA item they would get their money back. You can tell them that the item carries no warranty but that it is tested working or something along that lines. If it does arrive DOA you should allow him to return it and refund him the money otherwise paypal will come to collect from you after he submits a claim.

Comment: I think I get the point but, what does DOA mean? thanks

Comment: Is there a way to transfer warranty from where you got the item from?

Comment: No, since it was an award from a big hardware company

Comment: DOA = Dead On Arrival, i.e. never works.

Comment: Did the company who gave you the hardware specifically say it is not for resale? If no, the company may have no problem selling your buyer a service contract (warranty) for the hardware. But if they did say not for resale, you would jeopardize your business relationship with them should they ever find out... and one way they could find out is if the buyer approaches them and asks to be quoted a service contract on the hardware they bought from you on eBay.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably have to sell it as a second hand item without warranty. As it is virtually new you can describe it as **'Near New - Never Used'**. However, if others are selling the same or similar with a warranty you would need to provide a discount compared to the others.

Comment: ok, I agree with you

Comment: Depending on your legislation, as who (private vs. business) and to whom you sell (private vs. business) this may not be possible.

Comment: @cbeleites - based on the question as a one off item being sold, it is most likely that it would be sold as a private sale (especially in offering no warranty).